# how open image by clicking on a label c# ( image name is in sqlite database )?

Tags: c#, image, sqlite, label

I have a project with sqlite database.
I save images in folder " pics " ( into debug folder) & their name in the database ( column "docpic") .
When I click in a row , related image name sit as label10.text ..
By clicking on label10 how I open image by Windows Photo Viewer??

Comment: `Process.Start`

Answer (score 0):

In properties add eventHandler on event `Click`
Or by hands in form constructor add listener to label

```
label10.Click += LoadImage;
```

and write method

```
string ImagePath = @"c:\ImagesPath\";
private void LoadImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // cast sender to label so we can get access to it properties
    var label = (Label)sender;
    // compose path from folder path and image name
    var imgPath = ImagePath+label.Text;
    //Load image
}
```

p.s. How to find relative path:
Lets imaging that you have this structure of folders

```
/Project
    /Bin
        /Debug
            THIS_IS_YOUR.EXE
        /Images
            Image1.jpg
            Image2.jpg            
    /Obj
    /Properties
```

Then path to a folder will be

```
string dirPath = @"../Images/";
```

For more information visit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cd_(command)

Comment: label10.text is image name . thats not image path

Comment: where you keep path? or it is some static folder on specific place?

Comment: i dont save path .  i save images in folder ( pics) into folder ( debug) . and the names in the database . the path must be something like : "//pics//" ???

Comment: Yes, you need to use relative path in that way. Relative to your exe file. For example if you have `exe file` and `pic folder` in one level then just `pic//`.

Comment: excuseme . whats the answer of my problem finally ?

Comment: @hadielton check answer